# Saving plots as EMF files

Tags: r, plot

I am having an issue with the `emf()` function from the `devEMF` package.

The code I am using -

```
library(devEMF)
emf(file = "trial.emf")
plot(1:10, seq(10, 100, 10), type = "l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Distance")
#sample plot
dev.off()
```

[image: Output]

This does not have the plot line but does have everything else (labels, axis ticks, title).

[image: Desired_Output]

Am I missing some graphics package?

```
sessionInfo()
#R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
#Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

#locale:
#[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United # 
#States.1252   
#[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
#[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

#attached base packages:
#[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

#other attached packages:
#[1] devEMF_3.6

#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#[1] tools_3.3.2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of the defaults in that function are not ideal if you are trying to view outside of LibreOffice.

try this:

```
library(devEMF)
emf(file = "trial.emf", emfPlus = FALSE)
plot(1:10, seq(10, 100, 10), type = "l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Distance")
dev.off()
```

Make sure that `emfPlus = FALSE`. If you view the plot generated by `emfPlus = TRUE` in LibreOffice you will see it looks fine. Use `emfPlus = FALSE` when working with other viewers.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, what is `emfPlus`?

Comment: You can read about it in the help. Run `?emf` in you R terminal and see the Details section. I had never heard of it before until I looked at this tool just now. It seems like it is a new more versatile EMF format that LibreOffice supports.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the program being used to view the resulting emf graphic does not support EMF+ records.

As alluded in JMT2080AD's answer, the devEMF library can produce either "EMF" or "EMF+" files.  The newer EMF+ format (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230724.aspx) has been around since 2007 and is supported by more recent closed-source programs (i.e., Office 2010) but support is missing from old programs (e.g., older versions of Adobe Illustrator) and spotty in many open-source programs (e.g., LibreOffice, Inkscape).

For better or for worse, EMF+ records are embedded within EMF comment records, which means older programs will silently ignore them.

I find that the devEMF defaults produce acceptable files for Microsoft Office 2010 and LibreOffice >5.1.6.  While LibreOffice support for EMF+ is incomplete, the unsupported features are turned off by default in the call to `emf()`.  That said, JMT2080AD's suggestion of setting `emfPlus = FALSE` in the call to `emf()` is likely to make the files viewable by more programs (at the cost of losing features such as transparency and anti-aliasing).

(Disclosure: I am the author of the devEMF package)

Comment: Makes sense, I was using Paint to view because that was the "suggested" application to view EMF files.